# jquery code interrupt with other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I think my problem is very small, but i still need for help in my jquery code, I think it's all about js syntax:

```
$(function() {

    // Options for SuperBGImage
    $.fn.superbgimage.options = {
            randomtransition: 2, // 0-none, 1-use random transition (0-7)
            z_index: -1, // z-index for the container
            slideshow: 1, // 0-none, 1-autostart slideshow
            slide_interval: 2000, // interval for the slideshow
            randomimage: 1, // 0-none, 1-random image
            speed: 'slow' // animation speed
     };
     // initialize SuperBGImage
     $('#thumbs').superbgimage().hide();
});



$(function() {
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){
    $j('.menu-nav li').hover(
        function() {
            $j(this).addClass("active");
            $j(this).find('.ulwrapper').stop(false, true).fadeIn();
            $j(this).find('.ulwrapper .ulwrapper').stop(false, true).fadeOut('fast');
        },
        function() {
            $j(this).removeClass("active");        
            $j(this).find('div').stop(false, true).fadeOut('fast');
        }
    );
    $j('.ulwrapper').hover(
        function() {
            $j('.parent').addClass("active_tab");
        },
        function() {
            $j('.parent').removeClass("active_tab");        
        }
    );
});
});
```

the first code is for the Big image where the other is to work with my multi-level menu. I tried to workaround this by changing

```
$(function() {
```

to

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
```

but the browser only runs one code! and gives me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
(anonymous function)
```

I am waiting your help, thanks too much.

Comment: Why are you calling ".noConflict()"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you call jQuery.noConflict, the "$" binding won't work anymore.  You don't say *why* you're calling it, but you can use just "jQuery" instead of "$".  Your "$j" variable is local to that function where you call "noConflict".

Also, it doesn't make sense to do this:

```
$(function() {
  $(function() {
    // ...
  });
});
```

which is what you're doing in that second "ready" handler.  That is, you're setting up a "ready" handler from *inside* another one, which makes no sense really.

Comment: that's right, thanks for help. both functions now run just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For using $j in your script,you should insert following code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $j=jQuery.noConflict();
        </script>
```

Best Luck..

Comment: I only removed the noConflict as proposed by Pointy, but really thanks for participating.